# Azure , connecting two virtual machines without using virtual network gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

How to connect two virtual machines without using virtual network gateway in azure??
(The two vm's have been created in two different virtual networks)

Comment: Connect them *how*? Not sure what you're asking (please edit your question to clarify). But... seems more suited to ServerFault than StackOverflow, since this doesn't sound programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This are different Connectivity scenarios for Vnet to Vnet in Azure, and then you can connect your VMs from each other:

1. **VNets are in a same location**: [Create a virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-create-peering). It can work on  different deployment models and subscriptions, but except different locations. **Peering doesn't need Vnet gateway.**
2. **VNets are in different locations**:[Create a VPN Gateway to connect different VNets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vnet-vnet-rm-ps?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json#samesub). This work on all different Vnets from different deployment models , subscriptions, locations.This need to create VPN gateway.
3. **VNets are in different locations**:You can use VPN software on your VM to connect each other if your VMs are in different location. This also doesn't need Vnet gateway.
4. **VNets are in different locations**:You can also add IIS service on your VMs, and you can connect VMs from public traffic.

If your Vnets are in same location , **creating Vnet peering** is best choice.

Comment: Hi, @s.saptha maaleekaa, If this answer is helpful to you ,please mark it as an answer to help more people. Thanks!